# Stack Overflow / reddit voting system in php

Tags: php, voting

I'm looking for examples of how to implement a StackOverflow / reddit voting system in php.

Basically I want the Up and Down arrow box.  Are there any good examples out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of scripts [out there](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=php+voting+-poll&btnG=Search&meta=) but it's not too hard to do yourself.

I've used jQuery (to handle AJAX) and a small PHP script before. For example, some pseudo-code:

```
// Some checking for recent votes from this user is appropriate here
if (isset($_POST['voteType'], $_POST['postId']) && $user->loggedIn) {
    // insert vote into database if not already inserted
    echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
} else {
    // bad request/hack attempt
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Bad parameters sent'));
}
```

and then some jQuery:

```
$('#upVote').click(function() {
    $.post('vote.php', {voteType: 'up', postId: 42}, 'updateIcon(data, textStatus)', 'json');
});

function updateIcon(data, textStatus) {
    // If error = false highlight the upvote icon
    // else show the error message returned
}
```

[jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)