# Voting box (plus/minus, not star rating)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a voting script/widget (preferably jQuery), but not a star rating one, one with +1 and -1 options like this (admire my profesionnal MSPaint skills ^^) :

[image]

Anyone know about one ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: did you try google? http://ad1987.blogspot.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html

Comment: professional mspaint skills? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uk2sPl_Z7ZU :)

Comment: @Alec Smart : Yeah I know, I suck compared to this guy ! Anyway, I've already seen some voting block like the one I doodled, but I can't remember the website. I've searched google for 2 hours now, with all the keywords I could think of, and I didn't find anything close, except for the page you gave me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490969/stack-overflow-reddit-voting-system-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using ajax.

Recommend you set up some ajax listener page and ping with some userID and vote (1,-1) or something along those lines.

This assumes you have a userID and login credentials etc. Or you can register it against their IP or something.

Basically:

ajaxListener.php?ID=123456&vote=1

send the ajax listener, and then have the total vote count update when the ajax is complete (have your ajax listener echo back a string of data lets say):
voteTotal=10~totalVote=95

Once you read this with ajax, split it with javascript:
var split1=responseText.split("~");
var voteScore=split1[0];
var voteCount=split1[1];

not tested but this should work and complete what you are thinking.

ajax: 
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

```
$.ajax({ url: "ajaxTool.php?id="+idVariable, context: document.body, 
success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }});
```