# Creating a Simple Voting System with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm doing a fairly primitive voting system with PHP.

MySQL PHP

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)): ?>
<div class="item" data-postid="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-score="<?php echo $row['vote'] ?>">
  <div class="vote-span"><!-- voting-->

//
    <div class="vote" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" data-action="up" title="Vote up">
//

      <img src="//placekitten.com/10/10"/>
    </div><!--vote up-->
    <div class="vote-score"><?php echo $row['vote'] ?></div>

//       
    <div class="vote" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" data-action="down" title="Vote down">
//        

      <img src="//placekitten.com/g/10/10"/>
    </div><!--vote down-->
  </div>

  <div class="post"><!-- post data -->
    <h2><?php echo $row['name']?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $row['title'] ?></p>
  </div>
</div><!--item-->
<?php endwhile?>
```

I'm mostly focused at the text between the `//`.  First, I set two data attributes in hopes of using them later with javascript;  I set `data-action` to either `up` or `down` to tell if it was an upvote or a downvote.  I also set the `data-id` attribute to the current row ID key from my MySQL table.

Through my logic, I could then go through javascript jquery and cause the PHP code to execute when clicked, and add/subtract the number from the correct row in MySQL.

I tried the Javascript just more or less as an expirement:

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('action')=='up'){
        //PHP code here
    }
});
```

Needless to say, that didn't work, since PHP and Javascript don't play like that since PHP is serverside.  Next, I thought I could call a PHP function in my Javascript conditional - but there seems like there must be an easier way to do what I am attempting.  I've been looking at numerous tutorials, and they're either outdated or specific to other projects.  I checked around SO, and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013424/php-voting-one-vote-per-ip-per-day-code-help-needed), but it's geared towards allowing an IP to have vote limitations.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480520/simple-php-voting-system) looks similar to what I'm doing, except I can't really figure out how they have it set up, as they don't have how they call the function

TL;DR My problem is calling a PHP function on a div click that will place data into the correct ID of a MySQL row.  AJAX seems the way to go, but I'm unsure on how to implement it.

Comment: You need to look into AJAX, such that on an Javascript event (like click) you make a request to a PHP script, pass in your data, and then get and display the response.

Comment: as you have guessed, javascript (the client/browser) cannot directly execute php, as it is server-side. Basically you need to use ajax (javascript) to make a request to a php script that executes what you want

Comment: I thought AJAX was just for asynchronous stuff for PHP, can I also pass variables specific to each column to that PHP?  How would I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an AJAX call:

```
$('.vote').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your-script.php",
            data: {
                id: $(this).data('id'),
                vote: $(this).data('action')
            }
        })
            .done(function (msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        });
});
```

Now you can get the values in the script via `$_POST['id']` and `$_POST['action']`.

If you want to create it in PHP you've to put a form around the up and down button and give the submit button the desired text/image.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use AJAX for this functionality...you are close, add an ajax call inside your handler:

```
$('.vote').click(function(){
    if ($(this).data('action')=='up'){
        //jquery ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: "../pathToPhpFile/phpFile.php",
            data: { dataToBeSentToServer: someData },
            success: function(data){
                //var data is data passed back from PHP script
                $("#idOfDiv").html(data.html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

May I also add, you should be using PDO for your mysql connections.

https://www.php.net/PDO